# Laravel collection orderBy relation column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have one to many relation in laravel:

1. types
2. products - type_id, price

How can i get $types order by products lowest price?

Example:

- type_1 has: product_x - 10€, product_y - 15€
- type_2 has: product_a - 20€, product_b - 100€
- type_3 has: product_e - 12€, product_f - 200€

so types should be in order: type_1, type_3, type_2.

I tried this:

```
$types = $types->whereHas('products', function($q) use($order_by_price){
            $q->orderBy('price', $order_by_price);
        });
```

but didn't work.

Also i tried join(), but it ruined the collection somehow. Probably because of the same column names in types and products table.

[Here you got screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuzM0.png)

Comment: You're saying that the types to product relationship is one to many so how will you order by the product price when there's many products? Which product will be the one to order by for each type?

Comment: Lowest or highest price on product. Means i want to have $types ordered by their products lowest/highest price.

Comment: can you try `$types->toSql()` and get the sql query?

Comment: select * from `types` where `category_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and exists (select * from `products` where `types`.`id` = `products`.`type_id` and `price` >= ? and `price` <= ? order by `price` asc)

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
$type->products()->orderBy('price')->get();
```

or

```
Product::orderBy('price')->get();
```

If you want a more detailed answer please share more code(models, controllers etc) so I know how I can use the different models/solution

Comment: but i try to get $types not $products

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a one to many relationship you will need to aggregate. I find it easier to go at it the other way around i.e. group all products by their type and order by the minimum price.

```
 $types = Product::with('type')->groupBy('type_id')
         ->select('type_id', \DB::raw('MIN(price) as minPrice'))
         ->orderBy('minPrice')
         ->get()
         ->pluck('type');
```

This assumes you have the type relationship defined in the product with the name "type".

Comment: Is there any possibility to use pluck() function with paginate()? Checkout screenshot of my controller, please so you can understand how i need to use this. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Well you can do `paginate(9)` instead of `->get()->pluck()` but then in your view you will need to do `$item->type` to get the type out of each item in a page.

Comment: That I can't do because in my view I am displaying a list of $types, so i have foreach on types. And also your solution is getting me all the types but i only need $types from certain categories (screenshot - whereIn condition).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you gather all your filters and apply them all together. You can do something like the following.

```
$min_price = request('min_price');
$max_price = request('max_price');
$order_by_price = request('order_by_price');

$types = Type::whereIn('category_id', $type_categories)->whereHas('products', function ($q) use ($min_price, $max_price, $order_by_price) {
    if (!is_null($min_price)) {
        $q->where('price', '>=', $min_price);
    }

    if (!is_null($max_price)) {
        $q->where('price', '<=', max_price);
    }

    if (!is_null($order_by_price)) {
        $q->orderBy('price', $order_by_price);
    }
})->paginate(9);
```

Comment: Whenever you don't get the expected output, you run the `->toSql()` on builder to get the actual query and modify according to your need.

Comment: this is what i got with your code:
select * from `types` where `category_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and exists (select * from `products` where `types`.`id` = `products`.`type_id` and `price` >= ? and `price` <= ? order by `price` asc)